# NOT NULL constraint failed: dashboard_profile.user_id

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, sqlite, django-models

I'm trying to save the last IP of User to the Profile module in Django but I get always `NOT NULL constraint failed` I know that `last_ip` should be set to`null=True` and I run this commands:`py .\manage.py makemigrations` and `py .\manage.py migrate`. if you have any suggestions to save IP to the user that will be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

```
#models.py 

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=150)
    last_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(max_upload_size=10485760, null=True, verbose_name="",default='default.jpg', blank= True, content_types=['image/png', 'image/jpeg'])
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

```
#forms.py 

class UpdateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=150, required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=150, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','email']

class UpdateAvatarBio(forms.ModelForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField()
    bio = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['avatar', 'last_ip', 'bio']
```

```
#views.py
def ip_client(request):
    return (
        x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        if (x_forwarded_for := request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        else request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    )
def profile(request):
    ip = ip_client(request)
    model = Profile(last_ip=ip)
    model.save() # Traceback suppose here is the issue
    if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    ...
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Comment: you want to modify the user ip everytime he visits profile views ?

Comment: I'm just testing it in the profile function but I want to change the `last_Ip` each time user log in with another IP address

Comment: have you solved your problem ? i have an idea how you can achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add the user to Profile before saving it

```
def profile(request):
    ip = ip_client(request)
    model = Profile(last_ip=ip)
    moddl.user=request.user      #Add this
    model.save() # Traceback suppose here is the issue
    if request.method == 'POST':
         ...
         ...
   return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Edit:
Since the user is OneToOne (which means it is a the primary key), so Your code shall be like this

```
def profile(request):
    ip = ip_client(request)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    profile.last_ip = ip
    profile.save()
    if request.method == 'POST':
         ...
         ...
   return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, Where should I pass this variable

Comment: if I add this `user=request.user` without using it like I am doing nothing

Comment: It should be model.user, please check the updated answer

Comment: I got this `UNIQUE constraint failed: dashboard_profile.user_id`

Comment: I think I need to use ForeignKey

Comment: Check the Edit of the answer

Comment: thank you for that information